# Share share with guest and use specific user id (virtd, kvm)

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I am trying to get a shared path setup between a QEMU/KVM guest and the host. The problem I'm having is that KVM runs as the libvirt-qemu user (Ubuntu distro) and thus won't have permissions to any of the host files.

Is there anyway to use the access writes of a particular host user for the shared path? (That is, other than simply running KVM as that user, or adding them to a group)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use NFS and idmapd or samba and cifs mounts? If this problem were understood as how do I get two computers to have a shared folder - then you can solve it with plenty of widely available tools / tricks.

Unless you need very specific speed advantages that can only come from a virt-io based path, I would go with a KISS solution.